# Is "eclectic combination" a pleonasm?

Tags: meaning, expressions, pleonasms

Doesn't the term eclectic also describe a mix/combination? Is it correct to use this expression?

Comment: What does the definition of eclectic say? Combination? Are all combinations eclectic?

Comment: Look at the second definition from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eclectic - `Made up of or combining elements from a variety of sources`.

Comment: OK, so ththose definitions aren't giving  you the answer. 'Eclectic' is a _broad_ variety, a combination from very different, possibly incongruent, sources. A regular 'combination' can be of collection of apples, but an 'eclectic combination' is a collection of apples, watermelon, blueberries, and dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherent to the meaning of *eclectic* is the idea of a mixture. The *eclectic philosophers* were a class of ancient philosophers who did not belong to, nor found any recognised school of thought, but drew ideas and doctrines from various schools.

Hence *eclectic* clearly implies a combination. However I know of no collective noun for a group of *eclectics*. And that is perhaps where the idea of an *eclectic combination* comes from, i.e. a group of people, each one of varying ideas.

The question always arises as to whether the combination is itself eclectic, whilst its constituent members were individually non-eclectic; or whether it is a combination made up of eclectic individuals. That much is not clear. If it were the latter it might be better to say *a group of eclectics*.

A third possibility is that *eclectic combination* could also be an attempt to say the same thing twice e.g. *His ideas are an eclectic combination*, in which case the use is definitely *pleonastic*.

Comment: The context in which I have heard the expression was something like this: `X actor had an eclectic combination of roles`. I am not 100% sure if these were the exact words, but it was similar.

Comment: @Seitaridis I would have thought you could achieve the same meaning by saying 'During his career Actor X played eclectic roles' - or possibly 'an eclectic range of parts'.